# How to make 2 methods, one by one Bigcommerce?

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I have problem with bigcommerce API. When I am updating a product, or deleting all images, it works fine. But, together the methods are taking long to load and doing nothing. This is my code:

```
       Bigcommerce_Api::configure(array(
                    'store_url' => $storeURL,
                    'username' => $APIuser,
                    'api_key' => $APIkey
                ));

                Bigcommerce_Api::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
                Bigcommerce_Api::verifyPeer(false);

$fields = array(
            'name' => $data['title'],
            'type' => 'physical',
            'description' => $data['description'],
            'price' => $data['price'],
            'categories' => array(($catCreated ? $catID->id : $catObject[0]->fields->id)),
            'availability' => 'available',
            'weight' => '0.5',
            'sku' => $data['sku'],
            'search_keywords' => $data['tags']
        );

        Bigcommerce_api::updateProduct($id, $fields);

        Bigcommerce_api::deleteProductImages($id);
```

Where is the problem? Why I can't do 2 methods one after another?
documentation: https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php